# How do I access Outlook365 mailbox using impersonation using .NET?

Tags: oauth, office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, impersonation

I'm using this code:

```
        var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .WithTenantId(tenantId)
            .Build();

        var ewsScopes = new [] { "https://outlook.office365.com/.default" };
        var authResult = await cca.AcquireTokenForClient(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);

        var service = new ExchangeService
        {
            Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authResult.AccessToken),
            Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"),
            ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "mailbox@user.com"),
            TraceListener = new TraceListener(),
            TraceEnabled = true,
            TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All
        };

        Folder inbox = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
```

The code throws a `ServiceRequestException` (403) on the last line, and trace logs contains the error:

> x-ms-diagnostics: 2000008;reason="The token contains not enough scope to make this call.";error_category="invalid_grant"

Do I need to expand the `ewsScopes`? Or is this because I'm lacking the correct permissions in Azure? Which roles/permissions do I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the token your using in

> Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authResult.AccessToken),

in jwt.io

What you should see in the roles is

[image]

If you don't have that role it means your application registration isn't correct (eg you have added the delegate permission instead of Application permission which is a common mistake).

Comment: Thanks - that's useful information. The Azure admins are currently looking into how the permissions were set up. I'll mark this as the accepted answer if they are able to resolve it.